# Dynamic importing files from multiple folders using JavaScript to supply single export statement

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I've got a Proof Of Concept I'm working on where I'm creating a SaaS product that has multiple product modules.

Each product module will exist in a folder in a `modules` folder in the file system.

Each `<product-module>` folder will then have a `routes` folder with a file (`index.ts`) that holds the `routes` for the product module.

I'm doing this using Vue 3 along with Vue Router 4.

An example is illustrated below:

```
<project-folder>
- [src]
  - [modules]
    - [another-example]
      - [components]
      - [routes]
        - index.ts
      - [services]
      - [views]
    - [example]
      - [components]
      - [routes]
        - index.ts
      - [services]
      - [views]
    - moduleRoutes.tx
```

I've tried to do the follow (in the `moduleRoutes.ts` file), but the code is not able to find the files:

```js
import * as moduleRoutes from "/src/**/routes/*";

export default moduleRoutes;
```

The error being returned is:

```
Cannot find module '/src/**/routes/*' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I have also tried changing the import statement to:

```js
import * as moduleRoutes from "./**/routes/*";
```

But it too isn't resolving the files in the folders.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

---

Update:

I've since done some further research into added capabilities of WebPack, and found `require.context`.

With this, I've modified `moduleRoutes.ts` (renamed to `.js` for the time being) to look like this:

```js
const moduleRoutes = [];

const requireRoutes = require.context(
  "../",
  true,
  /^(.+?)\/(routes)\/(index.ts)$/,
  "lazy"
);

requireRoutes.keys().forEach((filePath) => {
  requireRoutes(filePath).then((module) => {
    module.routes.forEach((route) => moduleRoutes.push(route));
  });
});

export default moduleRoutes;
```

I'm then importing `moduleRoutes.js` into `index.ts` main entry file:

```js
const moduleRoutes = await require("@/modules/modulesRoutes.js");
```

When I `console.log` the result out (below) I'm 95% of the way there:

```js
console.log("moduleRoutes", moduleRoutes.default);
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "component": {
      "template": "<div>Another Example</div>"
    },
    "name": "module-another-example",
    "path": "/another-example"
  },
  {
    "component": {
      "template": "<div>Example List</div>"
    },
    "name": "module-example",
    "path": "/example"
  }
]
```

The bit that's not working is trying to iterate over the `moduleRoutes` array, nothing is displayed when I do the following:

```js
for (const route in moduleRoutes.default) {
  console.log("route in moduleRoutes.default", route);
}
```

Does anyone have any further ideas?

Comment: You have to manually import them all yourself or write a loader that imports them at the start of the program

Comment: Why did you think `import * as moduleRoutes from "/src/**/routes/*";` would work? I have never seen that documented in any module/package system. You always have to list all packages and the * is only for importing all symbols from one package.